# Subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand this below proof.

> Given $S$ a linearly independent set of vectors in $V$ and $S' \subset S$ a subset, then $S'$ is also linearly independent.

If $S$ is finite to start with or even countable, I'm fine with the proof. In the case where $S$ is uncountably infinite, I don't know if I fully buy this proof.

> Suppose we have $\sum\limits_{v_{\alpha} \in S'} c_{\alpha} v_{\alpha} = 0$. By defining $c_{\alpha} = 0$ for $v_{\alpha} \in S \setminus S'$, we can interpret this as $0 = \sum\limits_{v_{\alpha} \in S} c_{\alpha} v_{\alpha}$. As $S$ is linearly independent, all the $c_{\alpha} = 0$, so $S'$ is linearly independent as well.

My problem is this. By using $v_{\alpha}$, we're "allowing" $S$ to be uncountably infinite by referencing what is in effect an arbitrary indexing set .The next step of extending the sum to $S$ really means "add $0 $ as many times as necessary." The infinite series of $0$ is convergent and sums to $0$, so that's fine, but I really don't know what adding $0$ uncountably many times looks like. I'm inclined to think there has to be some further assumptions built into $S$ or at least the set difference $S' \setminus S$. I don't want to assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: An infinite set is linearly independent if every finite subset is linearly independent. As you see, there are no infinite sums in this definition.

Comment: But what confuses me is that in this theorem I'm trying to prove, $S'$ could be an infinite subset, because there is some notion of an infinite set of linearly independent vectors, $S$.

Comment: Naturally, $S'$ can be infinite (an infinite set has infinite subsets :). If any finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent, then this is obviously true for $S'$.

Comment: Adding uncountably many $0$s “looks like” and equals $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that proof is sloppy in the infinite case. Given the usual definition of linear independence of infinite sets:

> An infinite set $S$ is linearly independent if every finite subset of
> $S$ is linearly independent

it is not correct to start a proof with:

> Suppose we have $\sum\limits_{v_{\alpha} \in S'} c_{\alpha} v_{\alpha} = 0$

since nowhere in the definition is a sum over all elements considered. Note though, that we now essentially have two different definitions of linear independence: one for infinite sets and one for finite sets. Using this definition, a proof would go:

Suppose $S$ is linearly independent and infinite, and $S'\subseteq S$.  If $S'$ is finite, $S'$ is linearly independent since $S$ is.  So suppose $S'$ is infinite, and $T \subseteq S'$ is finite.  Then since $S' \subseteq S$, $T$ is a finite subset of $S$, and so since $S$ is linearly independent, so is $T$.  So every finite subset of $S'$ is linearly independent; so $S'$ is linearly independent as well.

Note that here you'll need a separate proof for the case where $S$ is finite, because there is a different criterion for linear independence in that case.

It's possible, though, that this proof is from a source using a different definition of linear independence and a different definition of summation, where infinite sums are allowed (assuming only finitely many terms are nonzero.)  In that case, the proof would be valid.

Comment: Just one question: is the condition that only finitely many terms are non-zero necessary and sufficient for the sum to exist? I ask only because I've seen this condition in several other contexts.

Comment: You could define sums with countably many non-zero terms, assuming it was convergent as an infinite series in the usual calculus sense.  However, in the context of an arbitrary vector space cannot consider questions of convergence because that requires more structure to your space, such as a norm.  And sums with uncountably many nonzero terms aren't sensible.